# Powershell append child to XML using XPath

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Gurus,
I am trying to add exclusion paths to an AppLocker Policy xml. It is fairly structured, but dotted notation doesn't work, as I need to use attributes to get to the correct node to append to.

```
<AppLockerPolicy Version="1">
  <RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="AuditOnly">
    ...
    <FilePathRule Id="2345" Name="All files located in the Program Files folder" Description="Allows members of the Everyone group to run applications that are located in the Program Files folder." UserOrGroupSid="sid" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\*" />
      </Conditions>
      <Exceptions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder1\*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder1:*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder2\*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder2:*" />
      </Exceptions>
    </FilePathRule>
```

Getting down to selecting the exceptions node is already hurting my eyes:

```
$xmldata = New-Object XML
$xmldata.Load("applocker.xml")

$xmldata.SelectSingleNode("/AppLockerPolicy/RuleCollection[@Type='Exe']/FilePathRule[@Name='All files located in the Program Files folder']/Exceptions")
```

Now got to creating the new node I want to add:

```
$newnode = $xmldata.CreateElement("FilePathCondition")
$newnode.InnerXml = '<FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder3:*" />'
```

But I cannot append it. It just isn't there. btw, the only it doesn't give an error is this:

```
$($xmldata.SelectSingleNode("/AppLockerPolicy/RuleCollection[@Type='Exe']/FilePathRule[@Name='All files located in the Program Files folder']/Exceptions")).AppendChild($newnode)
```

which I am sure is not the nicest solutions.

Could you enlighten me please as to how do I add a simple line to XML?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say *"dotted notation doesn't work"* ?

This works:

```
# using a Here-String as demo, in real life you would load the XML from file
[xml]$xmldata = @"
<AppLockerPolicy Version="1">
  <RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="AuditOnly">
    <FilePathRule Id="2345" Name="All files located in the Program Files folder" Description="Allows members of the Everyone group to run applications that are located in the Program Files folder." UserOrGroupSid="sid" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\*" />
      </Conditions>
      <Exceptions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder1\*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder1:*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder2\*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder2:*" />
      </Exceptions>
    </FilePathRule>
 </RuleCollection>
</AppLockerPolicy>
"@

# find the Rule node with the specified 'Name' attribute in the 'FilePathRule' child node
# Perhaps easier would be to use the 'Id' attribute if you know the value for it..
$rulesNode = ($xmldata.AppLockerPolicy.RuleCollection | 
                Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 'Exe' }).FilePathRule | 
                Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'All files located in the Program Files folder'} |  
                Select-Object -First 1

# create a new node and provide it with a 'Path' attribute
$newnode = $xmldata.CreateElement("FilePathCondition")
$newnode.SetAttribute("Path", "%PROGRAMFILES%\folder3:*")
# add the new node to the $rulesNode
[void]$rulesNode.Exceptions.AppendChild($newnode)

# ready, save the updated XML
$xmldata.Save("D:\Test\test.xml")
```

Or use Xpath:

```
# find the Rule node with the specified 'Name' attribute in the 'FilePathRule' child node
# Perhaps easier would be to use the 'Id' attribute if you know the value for it..
$rulesNode = $xmldata.SelectSingleNode("/AppLockerPolicy/RuleCollection[@Type='Exe']/FilePathRule[@Name='All files located in the Program Files folder']")

# create a new node and provide it with a 'Path' attribute
$newnode = $xmldata.CreateElement("FilePathCondition")
$newnode.SetAttribute("Path", "%PROGRAMFILES%\folder3:*")
# add the new node to the $rulesNode
[void]$rulesNode.Exceptions.AppendChild($newnode)

# ready, save the updated XML
$xmldata.Save("D:\Test\test.xml")
```

Output:

```xml
<AppLockerPolicy Version="1">
  <RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="AuditOnly">
    <FilePathRule Id="2345" Name="All files located in the Program Files folder" Description="Allows members of the Everyone group to run applications that are located in the Program Files folder." UserOrGroupSid="sid" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\*" />
      </Conditions>
      <Exceptions>
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder1\*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder1:*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder2\*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder2:*" />
        <FilePathCondition Path="%PROGRAMFILES%\folder3:*" />
      </Exceptions>
    </FilePathRule>
  </RuleCollection>
</AppLockerPolicy>
```

Comment: Hi Theo
Many thanks for the reply.

First case gives me "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.". 

I believe the first example errors out since I have more than one filepathcondition. I need specifically the one that has that name. But when you use dotted notation, you are pointing to append to any FilePathRule. Can I use attributes in the dotted notation?

the 2nd example works a treat :) thanks a million Theo